# stacking div on top of another

Tags: html, css

I have 2 div inside a wrapper div. I wanted to stack div2 below div1 but it keep overlay div 1 instead. Can anyone help ?

Here my code

**CSS:**

```css
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Wallpoet');
 body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.div1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
.compass {
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 190px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -1%;
  overflow: hidden;
}


**HTML:**
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="div1">      
    </div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Have try solution like using absolute position but it doesn't work.

Comment: How about simply use a br tag between two divs and also remove their absolute positions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the css on div2 to position relative to the bottom

```
.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used absolute positioning to specifically place the `div` elements at the same position. Remove the absolute positioning (and float also), and the `div` elements line up one below the other:

```css
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Wallpoet');
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.div1 {
  height: 75%;
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
}
.div2 {
  height: 25%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="div1">      
    </div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/143/

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.div1 {
    background: #bdc3c7;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 75vh;
}

.div2 {
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25vh;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your're mixing several layouyt modes. If you use floats for this then you cant't mix it with absolute positioning...
Anyway div is a block tag, what means that your two divs should stack even if you don't set any css property to them, just give the a concrete height, for example 200px.

If you want to cover the full browser viewport, that is what I think you want then is enough with this:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}
.div1 {
   background-color: #bdc3c7;
   width: 100%;
   height: 75vh;
}
.div2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25vh;
  background-color: red;
}
```